# why wont my asp.net mvc application seed work properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following code to create entities and seed them with data for use in an asp.net mvc application. I am using code first and entity framework. I generate controllers and run the application but on the index.cshtml page my list is empty where the seed data should be.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("dataDb") {}

    public DbSet<Owner> Owners { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}


public class MyInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        // seed database here
        context.Owners.AddOrUpdate(
       new Owner()
        {
            //name=,
            //id=,
            Pets = new List<Pet>  {  new Pet()
        {
           //id=,
           //name=,              
        },
        new Pet()
        {
           //id=,
           //name=,               
        }}
        },

        new Owner()
        {
            //id=,
            //name=,
            Pets = new List<Pet>  {  new Pet()
        {
            //id=,
            //name=,,               
        }



        }
        }

        );

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public int PetId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual Owner Owner { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem:

```
 Database.SetInitializer(new MyInitializer()); //important for seed to work
```

add this line to the context constuctor:

```
 public MyContext() : base("dataDb") {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add it to your web.config. When it comes to deployment, you can easily remove it from the web.config by using configuration transformer.

```
<entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MyProject.MyContext, MyProject">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.MyInitializer, MyProject" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    ...
</entityFramework>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=OwnersPets; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\OwnersPets.mdf; Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionString>
```

Example conn string to use with localDb